Wedge in between toes on shabbos
One of the common ways to treat an ingrown toenail is to place a small rubber or plastic wedge in between the toe that is infected and the next toe to give it space and not apply pressure on the infected area.
This doesn't necessarily heal it, rather could just be there to provide relief for the individual, since the infected toe is not being pushed against its neighbouring toe.
Would this be an issue to wear on Shabbat (in a reshus harabim or to walk from one reshus to another) due to the fact that it's not a piece of clothing and there's a possibility it will fall out from between ones toes and become loose in the sock or shoe?

Seems like it might be similar to a wad of soft material placed inside a shoe (for a foot injury or just to pad it for comfort), where if the shoe is completely enclosed, it's fine without tying the wad in place (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 303:15). The Baal Hatanya, in his formulation of this halachah (303:17), adds that "it's like an ornament or clothing, since it serves the body's comfort just like any garment."

Shmirat Shabbat K'Hilchata (18:21) allows one to carry in the public domain

orthopedic supports inside one's shoes (but not in open sandals unless the support is firmly attached)
insoles to keep feet warm, absorb perspiration or provide a better fit

Commentators (e.g., Mishna Brura Ohr Olam to 303:48) explain this is permitted because (1) the inserts are not seen by others so there is no issue of marit ayin and (2) it is evident one is not doing it as a ploy, to transport the insert. R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach adds that they are manufactured for that objective only. See also Igrot Moshe OC 1:107.
All these reasons appear to permit the wedge you are asking about. From personal experience, I can say they rarely fall when properly set, of the proper size and worn with socks. Should they fall it would be a case of ones.
Of course, consult your rabbi
before implementing anything you learn here.
